# why django give an error when user wans to create a comment?

Tags: python, django, ajax, comments

I am developing a blog website with Django. I am getting an error in the create_comment view when an unauthorized user tries to submit a comment.

My view code is as follows:

Python

def comment_create(request, slug, pk):
pk = str(pk)

```
try:
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
except Post.DoesNotExist:
    # handle the case where the post does not exist
    return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'errors': {'post': ['Post with this ID not found.']}})

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = post

        # check if the user has the necessary permissions to comment on the post
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.user.has_perm('blog.change_post'):
                comment.save()

                return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'comment': comment.to_dict()})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'errors': {'post': ['You are not authorized to comment on this post.']}})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'errors': {'user': ['Please log in.']}})

    else:
        return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'errors': form.errors})

else:
    return render(request, 'blog/post_details.html', {'post': post})
```

My error is as follows:

{"success": false, "errors": {"post": ["Post with this ID not found."]}}

I think the problem is that I am not checking in my code whether the user is logged in or not. Currently, even if the user is not logged in, they can submit a comment.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Code I can add:

Python
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'errors': {'user': ['Please log in.']}})